# Php is not running on app engine, what is wrong with my yaml file?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

here is my yaml file , I don't know where I went wrong. php just give back Error: Server Error for a test echo.

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 5m

handlers:
  # Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

env_variables:
  # Replace project, instance, database, user and password with the values 
obtained
  # when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/XXXXX-166105:us-
east1:XXXX;dbname=XXXX
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'XXXXXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML is syntactically incorrect

1. You need to put `obtained` after `values` or comment out that line.
2. Remove the newline between `us-` and `east` .

You can e.g. try this out at [this](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) site and get better feedback than you get from your PHP based parser (which is not a very good implementation of a YAML parser).

Without those fixes you will not be able to proceed to fixing any semantic errors your YAML document might (still) have.